# Complex number problem involving modulus

Tags: complex-numbers

Find real number $a$ such that a complex number $z$ may satisfy the equation

$|z|^2 -2zi +2a(1+i)=0$

Where $i=\sqrt {-1}$

I came across this problem while attempting my teachers homework and made attempts to solve this. I assumed $z$ to be $p+iq$ and reached the conclusion that point $z$ is at a distance of $\sqrt{2}$ from the point $-1-i$ on the Argand plane. However i am unable to proceed from here.

Any help to solve this problem would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1. Perhaps show how you obtained the $\sqrt2$ distance. 2, "Find real number 'a' such that": haven you copied/read the question accurately?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that $z = (x + iy)$, the imaginary portion of the equation

$$|z|^2 - 2zi + 2a(1 + i) = 0$$

becomes $-2ix + 2ia = 0 \iff a = x$.

Therefore, requiring that $z$ have form $(a + iy)$ is both necessary and sufficient with respect to the imaginary portion of the equation.

Therefore, all values of $(a)$ must be determined so that for each such value, at least one real value for $y$ exists so that

$$(z = a + iy) ~~\text{and} ~~|z|^2 - 2zi + 2a(1 + i) = 0.\tag1$$

Since the imaginary portion of (1) above is now guaranteed to be satisfied, attention may be confined to the real portion of (1) above.

---

First of all, it is immediately obvious that $a = 0$ is viable, as it leads to $z = 0$, for which (1) above is satisfied.

Therefore, without loss of generality, $a \neq 0$. 
Under this assumption, the math is simplified by assuming that $y = ak ~ \implies z = a(1 + ik).$

Then $|z|^2 = a^2 (1 + k^2)$.

Therefore, the real portion of (1) above is transformed to

$$a^2(1 + k^2) + 2ak + 2a = 0 \iff a^2(1 + k^2) + 2a(1 + k) = 0. $$

Since it is assumed that $a \neq 0$, the above equation can be transformed to

$$a(1 + k^2) + 2k + 2 = 0 \iff k^2(a) + k(2) + (a + 2) = 0.\tag2 $$

---

Therefore, the entire problem has been reduced to identifying for which values of $a$ (2) above is solvable, where $k$ is required to be a real number.  It is immediate that $k$ is solvable if and only if the discriminant to (2) above is $\geq 0$.

Therefore, the problem reduces to identifying for which values of $a \neq 0$, you have that

$$\left(4 - 4a^2 - 8a\right) \geq 0 \iff (a^2 + 2a - 1) \leq 0.$$

$$a^2 + 2a -1 = 0 \implies a = \frac{1}{2}\left[-2 \pm \sqrt{8}\right] = -1 \pm \sqrt{2}.\tag3$$

Therefore, based on (3) above, for $a \neq 0$, (2) above is solvable if and only if

$$\left( ~-1 -\sqrt{2} ~\right) ~\leq ~a ~\leq ~\left( ~-1 + \sqrt{2} ~\right).\tag4$$

Since the range given in (4) above includes $a = 0$, the range given in (4) above is the final answer.

Answer (score 0):

When you expand out your equation, you can write it in terms of its real and imaginary parts. Remember that $0 = 0 + 0i$, so the real part of the left-hand side must equal zero (giving you one equation in terms of $x$, $y$ and $a$) and so must the right-hand side (giving you a second equation in terms of $x$, $y$, and $a$).

That's two equations in two unknowns, but the real part of the equation actually has another important property - you can write it as a sum of squares and a residual, in a way that offers at least one obvious choice of $x$ and $y$, which then leads to the desired value of $a$.

Comment: I tried this before and got x=a...and couldnt proceed with the 1st equation.do u want me to assume x &y as per my choice?

Comment: Assuming the problem is as you've written, then you just need to find one value of $a$ that will let you get a solution. If you put $x = a$ into the real part, then you get an equation in $x$ and $y$ that very strongly hints at values to make them work.

Comment: So is it just like i am free to put any value of x&y as per my choice for the sake of getting the ans?But if i assume x then am i not indirectly assuming a??then does it mean the problem is incomplete?

Answer (score 0):

Pair the equation with its complex conjugate:

$|z|^2-2zi+2a(1+i)=0$

$|z|^2+2\overline zi+2a(1-i)=0$

Subtracting the conjugated equation from the original gives a linear relation between $z$ and $\overline z$:

$-2i(z+\overline z)+4ai=0$

Thus $z+\overline z=2a$ forcing $z=a+yi$ for some real number $y$. Note that this implies that $a$ is just the $x$ coordinate on the locus you found (a circle with radius $\sqrt2$ centered at $(-1,-1)$), so if you have that locus in hand you should immediately be able to read off the domain.

Here I continue with the algebraic solution. Plug the known form $z=a+yi$ into the original equation:

$a^2+y^2-2ai+2y+2a(1+i)=0$

$y^2+2y+(a^2+2a)=0$

This has a real root for $y$, as required, iff the discriminant $4-4(a^2+2a)\ge0$, thus $a^2+2a-1\le 0$. So $a$ lies inclusively between the zeroes of $a^2+2a-1$:

$-1-\sqrt2\le a\le -1+\sqrt2$

which, as expected, matches the domain 9f $x$ coordinates for your circle.